# Selenium/WebDriver tearDown() don't close navigator

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, webdriver

I don't understand why my selenium java test doesn't close my Firefox windows at the end of the test.
Any ideas ?

Here is my code

```
public class ScenarioTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();


  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.popgom.fr/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

 @Test
  public void ScenarioTest() throws Exception { // My test code ... }

 @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
  }
 }
```

Comment: try to quit in main Test function.. if there it is working then sure there is an issue in After method

Comment: Thx for answering me. I already try to add driver.quit(); in my main, but nothing happens

Comment: have you try driver.close();

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work too

Comment: I would recommend to update selenium version, or downgrade firefox.

Comment: I don't understand, the driver.quit was working in an other project yesterday ...

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. It seems to be firefox version issue.

Comment: Well.. I fix it by configuring Selenium integration with Maven, works fine

Comment: Fixed ! It was just an element that wasn't visible in the page and block the process... So stupid !

Comment: @volnoboy Don't ask people to upgrade/downgrade just on the offchance, without even knowing their current versions

Answer (score -1):

Try with `AfterTest`,

```
@AfterTest
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
      }
     }
```

Might be work in your case. :) or you may be need to update the TestNg/Junit Version.